# How do I call out a value in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I get an Array value out of a function?

This worked:

```
var days = new Array();
days[1] = 'Sunday';
days[2] = 'Monday';
days[3] = 'Tuesday';
days[4] = 'Wednesday';
days[5] = 'Thursday';
days[6] ='Friday';
days[7] = 'Saturday';
alert(days[3]); // returns Tuesday
```

But if I put this in a function how do I get the alert() to work?

```
function mydays(){
var days = new Array();
days['Sunday'] = 1;
days[8] = 'Monday';
days[3] = 'Tuesday';
days[4] = 'Wednesday';
days[5] = 'Thursday';
days[6] ='Friday';
days[7] = 'Saturday';
}
alert(mydays(days[8])) //nothing should be Monday
alert(days[8]) // nothing should be Monday
```

What is the correct syntax?
Thank you.

Comment: Your JavaScript book doesn't teach you how to `return` from a function? Swap it for a different one at the earliest available opportunity.

Comment: When references explain arrays, they tend just lay the example out minus the function except for the alert(). This goes for books and online sources.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I spent a good part of a day researching this; all that I found, including on stackover, were variations of the top code without the wrapping function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `days` has been declared in the scope of the function `mydays`, you simply cannot access it from outside. However, you have some options:

#### 1. Return the value

Which seems to be what you want from `alert(mydays(days[8]))`. You need not pass the argument, simply do:

```
function mydays() {
    var days = new Array();
    days['Sunday'] = 1;
    days[8] = 'Monday';
    days[3] = 'Tuesday';
    days[4] = 'Wednesday';
    days[5] = 'Thursday';
    days[6] = 'Friday';
    days[7] = 'Saturday';
    return days; // return the whole array
}

alert(mydays()[8]) // get the 8th element of the array returned
```

#### 2. Make it global scope

```
var days = new Array(); // empty array

function mydays() {
    days['Sunday'] = 1;
    days[8] = 'Monday';
    days[3] = 'Tuesday';
    days[4] = 'Wednesday';
    days[5] = 'Thursday';
    days[6] = 'Friday';
    days[7] = 'Saturday';
}

alert(days[8]) // days is still empty array, we haven't called the function yet
mydays(); // will set the days' values
alert(days[8]) // will be now monday
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The same way you get any value out of a function: You return it. You aren't returning the array, so it gets created and goes away immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<script>
    function mydays(index) {
        var days = new Array();
        days['Sunday'] = 1;
        days[8] = 'Monday';
        days[3] = 'Tuesday';
        days[4] = 'Wednesday';
        days[5] = 'Thursday';
        days[6] = 'Friday';
        days[7] = 'Saturday';
        return days[index];
    }
    alert(mydays(8));
</script>
```